# Double NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

The functions I have are

```
i[d_,\[Tau]_,g_,w_]=-FractionBox["1", "8"] (-1+SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", SuperscriptBox["d", "2"]}]]) (2 SuperscriptBox["g", "2"]+SuperscriptBox["w", "2"]-SuperscriptBox["w", "2"] Cos[2g*\[Tau]])

a[\[Tau]_,g_,d_]=ArcCos[FractionBox["1", "4"] SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", "d"}]] (SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", "d"}]]+SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "+", "d"}]]+(SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", "d"}]]-SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "+", "d"}]]) Cos[g *\[Tau]])+FractionBox["1", "4"] SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "+", "d"}]] (SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", "d"}]]+SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "+", "d"}]]+(-SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", "d"}]]+SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "+", "d"}]]) Cos[g *\[Tau]])]

b[t_,w_,g_,d_]=Sqrt[-FractionBox["1", "8"] (-1+SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", SuperscriptBox["d", "2"]}]]) (2 SuperscriptBox["g", "2"]+SuperscriptBox["w", "2"]-SuperscriptBox["w", "2"] Cos[2g*t])]

c[\[Tau]_,w_,g_,d_]:=NIntegrate[b[t,w,g,d],{t,0,\[Tau]}]

e[\[Tau]_,g_,d_,w_]:=a[\[Tau],g,d]*\[Tau]/c[\[Tau],w,g,d]
```

Where all parameters except t and g are fixed (tau=4, d=0.5, w=5)

(sorry for the format but if you copy it to Mathematica you get the right functions)

Now as you can see my function c is a numerical Integral and my function e contains c as one of the building blocks. As vizaluisation here is the Code that plots my function e (just so you see that in theory a mean value should be existent):

```
\[Tau]=4
d=0.5
w=5
Plot[{e[\[Tau],g,d,w]},{g,0,5},AxesLabel->{Style["g",Bold,16]},PlotLabels->{Style["\[Tau](QSL)",Bold,13]}]
```

[image]

My Problem now is that I want to plot the Mean of function e over the interval and to do that I would need to calculate something along the Lines of

```
1/j*NIntegrate[e[\[Tau]_,g_,d_,w_],{g,0,j}]
```

and to plot this function

```
Plot[{1/j*NIntegrate[e[\[Tau]_,g_,d_,w_],{g,0,j}]},{j,0,5}]
```

which is the mean of e over the variable g in [0,5].
But if I enter a code above in Mathematica it gives me a ton of errors. I guess this is due to the fact that mathematica has no explicit expression for the function I want to integrate because it in itself contains a numerical integration.

A double Integral does not work because my first integration of c is the denominator of the function e and I dont want to Integrate over 1/c by just putting

```
1/j*NIntegrate[{a[\[Tau],g,d]*\[Tau]/(Sqrt[-FractionBox["1", "8"] (-1+SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", SuperscriptBox["d", "2"]}]]) (2 SuperscriptBox["g", "2"]+SuperscriptBox["w", "2"]-SuperscriptBox["w", "2"] Cos[2g*t])])},{{t,0,\[Tau]}},{g,0,j}]
```

some help yould be highly apreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Convert your code to `InputForm` prior to copy and paste into MSE.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You've got a lot of these `` in your code. What symbol is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

τ = 4;
d = 1/2; (* use exact values for known constants *)
w = 5;

i[d_, τ_, g_, 
   w_] = -(1/8) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - d^2]) (2 g^2 + w^2 - w^2 Cos[2 g*τ]) // 
   Simplify;

a[τ_, g_, d_] = 
  ArcCos[1/4 Sqrt[
      1 - 
       d] (Sqrt[1 - d] + Sqrt[
        1 + d] + (Sqrt[1 - d] - Sqrt[1 + d]) Cos[g*τ]) + 
     1/4 Sqrt[
      1 + 
       d] (Sqrt[1 - d] + Sqrt[
        1 + d] + (-Sqrt[1 - d] + Sqrt[1 + d]) Cos[g*τ])] // Simplify;

b[t_, w_, g_, d_] = 
  Sqrt[-(1/8) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - d^2]) (2 g^2 + w^2 - w^2 Cos[2 g*t])] // 
   Simplify;
```

Since `c` uses a numeric technique, its arguments should be restricted to being numeric. To control precision, use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision.

```
c[τ_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{ww, gg, dd, ττ},
  {ww, gg, dd, ττ} = SetPrecision[{w, g, d, τ}, 20];
  NIntegrate[b[t, ww, gg, dd], {t, 0, ττ}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]]

e[τ_, g_, d_, w_] := a[τ, g, d]*τ/c[τ, w, g, d]

Plot[{e[τ, g, d, w]}, {g, 0, 5},
 AxesLabel -> {Style["g", Bold, 16]},
 PlotLabels -> {Style["τ(QSL)", Bold, 13]}]
```

[image]

```
mean[j_?Positive] := Module[
  {jj = SetPrecision[j, 15]},
  1/jj*NIntegrate[e[τ, g, d, w],
    {g, 0, jj},
    WorkingPrecision -> 12,
    Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"]]
```

Calculation of `mean` is slow

```
(data = Table[{j, mean[j]}, {j, 0.05, 5, 0.075}];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {240.857, Null} *)

ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

**EDIT** Following the recommendation by Akku14 to redefine `c`

```
Clear[c, e, mean]

c[τ_, w_, g_, d_] = Assuming[g >= 0,
   Integrate[b[t, w, g, d], {t, 0, τ}]] // Normal

(* 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[3]) EllipticE[4 g, -(25/g^2)] *)

e[τ_, g_, d_, w_] := a[τ, g, d]*τ/c[τ, w, g, d]

mean[j_?Positive] := 
 Module[{jj = SetPrecision[j, 15]}, 
  1/jj*NIntegrate[e[τ, g, d, w], {g, 0, jj}, WorkingPrecision -> 12]]

Plot[mean[j], {j, 1/100, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not even know that there are such possibilities to modify a calculation. I will try to calculate it in my mathematica but I think my calculation time is limited to 1 min.
Thank you!

Comment: In this case `c ` can be done with `Integrate ` analyticaly, which makes things easier and faster.

Comment: @Akku14 - Thanks. Edited to use `Integrate`